# How to check If the current app process is running within a queue environment in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I applied a global scope to my models via a trait, but I don't want the global scope applied when the model is called/processed from my Redis queue.

How do I detect if the current instance is a queue process? just like we have this

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
    // The environment is local
}
```

to detect if the app is running in local or production.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply call the [`runningInConsole()` method](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Foundation/Application.html#method_runningInConsole) :

```
if (app()->runningInConsole()) {
```

or with [the App facade](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/App.html):

```
if (\App::runningInConsole()) {
```

to check if execution is happening via CLI.

Comment: Thanks. seems to be what I need. 

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for this. Both work in Laravel 9.

**First one**

Larvel registers \Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler in the service container if the app is running in the queue, it does not register that class when running in the console or with a web request. So the following check works and distinguishes between the queue and running on the console.

```
// true when code is in the queue
app()->resolved(\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler::class);
```

**Second one**

When Laravel starts a Queue Job there is an [event with a callback](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#job-events) you can use to attach some currently-running-in-queue flag in the service container.

```
// Within the boot method of a service provider
App::bind('processing-job', function ($app) {
    return false;
});
Queue::before(function (JobProcessing $event) {
    App::bind('processing-job', function ($app) {
        return true;
    });
});
```

Then you can run a check anywhere like this:

```
App::get('processing-job');
```

**Note**

When running tests, and env var QUEUE_CONNECTION is set to sync the test will think you are in a queued process. This is because when working in sync both your test and the job live within the same instance.